# Where am I going wrong in counting pairs where second element is less in array efficiently?

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, mergesort

Given an array of elements, return an array of values pertaining to how many elements are greater than that value in the given array?

The brute force approach with two loops is obvious here, with O(n^2) but I want to do better. Hence, I tried it using modifying merge sort. I made a node, which has two members. The actual value, and how many elements it is smaller than (count). Count is initialised to zero. My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <climits>
#include <set>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


class node 
{
public:
    int val;
    int count;
};

void merge(node *temp,int, int , int );
void mergesort(node *temp, int low, int high)
{
    int mid;
    if (low < high)
    {
        mid=(low+high)/2;
        mergesort(temp,low,mid);
        mergesort(temp,mid+1,high);
        merge(temp,low,high,mid);
    }
    return;
}
void merge(node *temp, int low, int high, int mid)
{
    int i, j, k;
    node c[50];
    i = low;
    k = low;
    j = mid + 1;
    while (i <= mid && j <= high)
    {
        if (temp[i].val < temp[j].val)
        {
            c[k] = temp[i];
            k++;
            i++;
            c[k].count = c[k].count + high-j+1;   // only change which should calculate
        }
        else
        {
            c[k] = temp[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    while (i <= mid)
    {
        c[k] = temp[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    while (j <= high)
    {
        c[k] = temp[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
    for (i = low; i <= high; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = c[i];
    }
}
int main()
{
    node a[20];
    node b[20];
    int i;
    cout<<"enter  the elements\n";
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i].val;
        a[i].count = 0;
    }
    mergesort(a, 0, 6);
    cout<<"sorted array\n";
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i].val<<" "<<a[i].count<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, the above outputs, 0 as count value for all elements, however, it sorts the elements correctly. For example, on input as,

```
3 4 5 9 2 1 3
```

O/P comes out to be,

```
1 0
2 0
3 0
3 0
4 0
5 0
9 0
```

Why count is 0?

Comment: `#define ll long long` I see these macros in people's questions frequently. Where do they come from? Who gave you that?

Comment: The `#define` is often misused for many things it is not meant for by too many programmers. Correct version would be `using ll = long long;` (if your compiler is new enough) or `typedef long long ll;` or remove the `ll` completely and use `long long` everywhere.

Comment: It might be a good idea to use `std::sort` instead of this (as this doesn't look like something that's going to be easy to mantain). But of course, that depends on your motivation behind this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following jumps to eye:

```
c[k] = temp[i];
k++;
i++;
c[k].count = c[k].count + high-j+1;   // only change which should calculate
```

Why is the value inserted into one element, and then the count updated in **next**? I see with my magic eye that increased count is overwritten with zero in the next iteration, giving you the result you have.

Rewriting this as:

```
c[k] = temp[i];
c[k].count = c[k].count + high-j+1;   // only change which should calculate
k++;
i++;
```

may help.

Comment: Thanks. So stupid of me making this mistake. Thanks for the help. :)